# Prepared PDO (MySQL) update statement

Tags: php, pdo

I'm curious what I'm doing wrong. To start off; I'm getting the infamous

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

Now; what I'm trying to do:

- ajax call to php script
- this php script loops through the $_REQUEST array and collects all the values that should be updated in the database
- dynamically generate the update query, which is then passed to a function

Everything seems to be working fine up to the point of passing the query to the function. Here's the function:

```
function modifyRecord()
    {
        global $db;
        $parameters = func_get_args();
        $query = array_shift($parameters);
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        try
        {
            $statement->execute($parameters);
        }
        catch (PDOException $error)
        {
            echo $error -> getMessage();
        }

    }
```

As this produces the error message I tried checking the contents of $parameters:

```
"UPDATE applications SET service=?,acronym=?,email=? WHERE id=2"
```

And also of $query:

```
"value1","value2","value3"
```

Is there anything I'm overlooking? If I'm reading the output correctly I'm trying to bind 3 variables and providing 3 values - but obviously PDO thinks differently :)

Thanks in advance for any input - I'm sure it's going to be something silly...

Comment: Shouldn't parameters being `"value1","value2","value3"`?

Comment: And `$query` `"UPDATE applications SET service=?,acronym=?,email=? WHERE id=2"` is this a mistake in your question or your actual error?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` of both variables? Perhaps the problem is that your parameters is a comma-separated list instead of an array.

Comment: @fabio: no that seems to be correct - that's the weird thing

Comment: Invert them and it will work

Comment: @jeroen: OK `var_dump` actually revealed they're both strings: `[0]=>
  string(62) "UPDATE applications SET service=?,acronym=?,email=? WHERE id=2"
  [1]=>
  string(42) ""value1","value2","value3""` Should I use the `explode` before actually passing the values to the statement?

Comment: It is correct they are both strings untill you process in the connection object

Comment: The problem seems to be in the caller. Why is it passing the values as a single argument instead of separate arguments?

Comment: In addition to exploding, you need to remove the quotes. It looks almost like a JSON array, except it's missing the `[]` brackets.

Comment: Actually, func_get_args() creates array from the function arguments; therefore I have an array composed of two strings ($parameters & $query). Trying to create an array out of the parameters string causes the message `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`...think I'm totally confused now; if I can believe `var_dump` output both variables are actually strings. But converting them to array causes error that explode expected string but received array...

Comment: Why this function is called "modify record"? There is nothing in the function body regarding modification, beside the fact it doesn't return anything

Comment: Considering nobody but me will ever see the name of the function and I know what it's supposed to be doing, function name is perhaps not all that important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening now (just an analysis):

```
function modifyRecord()
{
    global $db;
    $parameters = func_get_args();

    // in this point you say that $paremeters is 
    // [0]=> string(62) "UPDATE applications SET service=?,acronym=?,email=? WHERE id=2" 
    // [1]=> string(42) ""value1","value2","value3""

    // then you are doing this:
    $query = array_shift($parameters);

   // now with this array_shift you are giving the value
   // "UPDATE applications SET service=?,acronym=?,email=? WHERE id=2"
   // to the variable $query and the $parameters array has now only 1 element
   // the $parameters[0] which has the value
   // ""value1","value2","value3""
   // NOTE THE VALUE IS IN $parameters[0] which is the only element left after the array_shift


    $statement = $db->prepare($query); // here you are preparing the query, ok 
    try
    {
        $statement->execute($parameters); // here is the fault. execute expects an array with 3 elements like this:
        // $parameters[0] = "value1";
        // $parameters[1] = "value2";
        // $parameters[2] = "value3";

        // but instead execute gets this:
        // $parameters[0] = ""value1","value2","value3"";
        // so he says: i was expecting an array with 3 elements and all i got was an array which had only one element that had a string value.
        // SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

    }
    catch (PDOException $error)
    {
        echo $error -> getMessage();
    }

}
```

the solution is to explode the string of $parameters[0]. note: the "'s are part of the value. you need to get rid of them. so the correct should be:

The needed changes (solution):

```
function modifyRecord()
{
    global $db;
    $parameters = func_get_args();

    // in this point you say that $paremeters is 
    // [0]=> string(62) "UPDATE applications SET service=?,acronym=?,email=? WHERE id=2" 
    // [1]=> string(42) ""value1","value2","value3""

    // then you are doing this:
    $query = array_shift($parameters);

   // now with this array_shift you are giving the value
   // "UPDATE applications SET service=?,acronym=?,email=? WHERE id=2"
   // to the variable $query and the $parameters array has now only 1 element
   // the $parameters[0] which has the value
   // ""value1","value2","value3""
   // NOTE THE VALUE IS IN $parameters[0] which is the only element left after the array_shift


   // lets create the $parameter_array from the $parameters[0]
   $parameter_array = explode(",",$parameters[0]);
   // and lets remove the " from the begin and the end of every element
   foreach ($parameter_array as $key => $a_parameter)
   {
       $parameter_array[$key] = trim($a_parameter, '"');
   }

    $statement = $db->prepare($query); // here you are preparing the query, ok 
    try
    {
        $statement->execute($parameter_array); // NOW its correct. we give execute what it wants: an array with 3 elements like this:
        // $parameter_array[0] = "value1";
        // $parameter_array[1] = "value2";
        // $parameter_array[2] = "value3";

    }
    catch (PDOException $error)
    {
        echo $error -> getMessage();
    }

}
```

working here http://3v4l.org/kQsAV

Comment: That looks very promising; thank you. I'll have a go myself later tonight.

Comment: That was it Sharky, you nailed it! Thank you so much - lesson for me for the future; function is passed 2 arguments; func_get_args() create array of the arguments but I needed array of arguments from the [1] element. Thanks so much again!!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it would seem that `func_get_args()` gives you an array that contains 2 strings: The query and the parameters.

If the order is wrong, you need to use `array_pop` instead of `array_shift`.

Furthermore you need to convert the parameters string to an array and you need to get rid of the quotes around your individual parameters. That would look something like (after you have popped the query of the array):

```
// written out for clarity

// $parameters is still a array containing one element, the string with the parameters
$params = array_pop($parameters);

// make an array containing 3 elements from the string
$params_array = explode(',', $params);

// get rid of the quotes
foreach ($params_array as $key => $value)
{
  $params_array[$key] = trim($value, '"');
}

try
{
    $statement->execute($params_array);
}
catch (PDOException $error)
{
    echo $error -> getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; but as far as I can tell the order or the arguments passed to the function is correct - first the query itself then the parameters. When I tried exploding both strings PHP told me they were both arrays already - nevertheless I will try your suggestion tonight. Thanks again

Comment: @TomasH Take a look at the first line of the code I posted, your parameter string is part of an array with one element (as far as I can see...) so you need to get that string and convert it to an array with 3 elements. Obviously if you can change the code that is calling the function as well, you should pass the parameters for the query as an array there...

Comment: Thanks again I really appreciate the effort. I'll have a go at this as well.

Answer (score -3):

> Now; what I'm trying to do:

You know, it's terrible way of asking questions. Don't tell the tale. Post the **code**.
Nobody actually knows what do you mean with "php script loops" and "dynamically generate".

Why make everyone scratch their heads and guess? Why not to post the very code you run?

But well, assuming your question not "What's wrong" but as "How to do". Create another method

```
function runQueryArray($query,$parameters)
{
    global $db;
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    return $statement->execute($parameters);
}
```

you need this function for the case like this - when you have an array with parameters instead of explicitly passed parameters.

And for goodness sake, **don't** use these explode-based "solutions" from the other answers.

Comment: unless his whole system follows a correct approach, he WILL explode an array of parameters to call this function - remember an element has csv-quoted value of `""value1","value2","value3""`. YES your approach IS the correct,but in this specific scenario with the limited piece of code he gave us, i don't know what is worse. to do the mess exploding arrays all around the rest of his code whenever there is a need for this call, or hide the mess inside a function and forget about it. if his code has not a nice clean approach from scratch, this has the potential to mess it more. oh, god.`¯\(°_o)/¯`

Comment: Sure, you can ignore the input, just forget that `$parameters` is a string with all arguments quoted and comma-separated and pretend it's an array. Then this function will work. Doesn't help the OP much though.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: thanks for your input; I did think about posting the whole code here but I didn't want to clutter the code segment that's causing the problem. What you posted does look like a cleaner approach and I'll definitely consider it.